# Which is more correct? '5 minutes left' or '5 minute left'?

Tags: singular-vs-plural

Is it '5 minutes left' or '5 minute left'?? which is correct? What about when it's 1 minute vs 1 minutes or 0 minute/0minutes

Answer (score 2):

As with other countable nouns, one is singular, other quantities (including zero) are plural. One minute, two or more minutes. In general, we do not talk about "zero minutes" when we mean "no time".

Comment: One interesting exception occurs when the number is used in a (sometimes hyphenated) adjectival term, for example: _thirty-minute timer; five-kilometer run, three-minute egg; 500 word essay_. In such cases, the noun typically retains its singular form.

Comment: I think this is an important point, @J.R. The rule that numbers other than 1 take a plural noun in English is so basic and pervasive that I suspect that questioner has been confused by this adjectival use.